# Subreports repeated many times on main report when preview

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I used subreport because watermark does not show line objects on it
so, I put a waterMark on main report and whole data in main report detail section. Now problem is that data is repeating (main report and sub report having same dataset).

Comment: Where did you place the sub report

Comment: in detail section of main report

Answer (score 0):

I Have Insert Group Section in Main Report and Put Sub Report in Group Section
and finally solved my problem of repeating sub report (or duplicate sub report)